# How to call PHP function without reloading?

Tags: javascript, php, html

In my test work, I want to send data to DB by pressing "Save" button and stay at the same page. But this button after sending data to DB opens /file.php and shown "Success".
I tried to solve the task by JS I found, but it doesn`t work.

```js
$('#sub').click( function() {
    $.post( $('myForm').attr('action'), $('#myForm :input').serializeArray(), function(info){ $('result').html(info);} );
    clearInput();
});

$('myForm').submit(function() {
    return false;
});

function clearInput() {
    $('#myForm :input').each( function() {
        $(this).val('');
    });
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        OneTwoThree
    </title>
</head>
<body>


<form id='myForm' action="db.php" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    Age: <input type="text" name="age"><br>
    <button id="sub">Send</button>
</form>

<span id="result"></span>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script/myjs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Callable PHP file:

```
<?php
    $conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    $db = mysql_select_db('mytestbd');

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];

    $q = "INSERT INTO `post`(`number`, `sometext`) VALUES ('$age','$name')";

    if(mysql_query($q))
        echo "Success";
    else
        echo "Fail";
    ?>
```

Comment: what "doesn't work"?  Any errors in your console? Also you missed the hash: `$('result')` so that bit won't do anything same with your myForm - which is why you are actually submitting the form instead of staying on the same page

Comment: try this:  e.preventDefault();

Comment: Thanks, Sanjay, I`ll try it now

Comment: Actually you'll need to add `e` to `$('#sub').click( function(e) {` (right after 'function')... THEN you can do `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Pete, can you, please type full code line in correct form? I can`t find mistake by myself. It my first day in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this block of js which includes some changes and adjustments (noted below):

```
$(document).ready(function() {               // ready wrapper (was missing in your code)

    $('#sub').click( function(e) {           // added 'e'
        e.preventDefault();                  // added to stop buttons default behavior
        $.post( $('#myForm').attr('action'), // added '#' to id locator
                $('#myForm').serialize(),    // reduced to just serialize the form data
                function(info){
                    $('#result').html(info); // added '#' to id locator
                    clearInput();            // moved clear form into success callback
                }
              );
    });

    $('#myForm').submit(function() {         // added '#' for id locator
        return false;                        // this submit handler is most likely
    });                                      // not needed, but doesnt hurt

    function clearInput() {
        $('#myForm :input').each( function() {
            $(this).val('');
        });
    }

});
```

---

**PS** Once you get the submission process working, you will want to switch your use of `mysql_*` functions to either mysqli or PDO (as `mysql_` is depreciated in php 5.5x, and removed in php7+).

Then after you switch, look into [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to safeguard from sql injection attacks.

Comment: Thnks a lot, IncredibleHat

Answer (score 1):

Just use a include statement.

```
if(mysql_query($q))
    echo "Success";
    include('yourFileWithTheForm.php');
else
    echo "Fail";
?>
```